# Defining a relative point with rotations

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics

I want to get a relative point (so it's current pos + a vector3 of directions)

so that when I rotate the gameObject it's still in the same relative point

Example: (say if it was 1 unit away from the gameObject in the x axis when rotation is 0, it should be 1 unit away form the gameObject in the z axis when rotation is -90)

here's what I tried: (center is a vector3 of the distance relative to the gameObject)

```cs
boxPos = new Vector3(
    center.x + transform.position.x + (transform.rotation.eulerAngles.y * (1 / 360) * center.x),
    center.y + transform.position.y,
    center.z + transform.position.z + (0.5f - (transform.rotation.eulerAngles.y * (1 / 360) * center.z))
    );
```

any way how to do so?

After many suggestions... here're the results:

**TEST 1:**

*Code:*

```cs
private void OnDrawGizmos()
{
    //center is a value I defined... it is the relative point
    //no need to care about extents... that's just box size
    Vector3 objectPosition = transform.position;
    Quaternion rotation = transform.rotation;
    boxPos = (rotation * (center - objectPosition)) + objectPosition;
    Gizmos.matrix = Matrix4x4.TRS(Vector3.zero, transform.rotation, transform.localScale);
    Gizmos.color = Color.red;
    Gizmos.DrawWireCube(boxPos, new Vector3(extents.x * 2, extents.y * 2, extents.z * 2));
}
```

*Result:*

> **0-0-0 POSITION:** it renders as if it was shifted `center/-2` units away from the expected point (as expected from the other notices).

> **ROTATION:** makes it behave weirdly

> **MOVEMENT:** doesn't affect it at all

> **OTHER NOTICES:** boxPos is just `center/-2` (so if center is `1, -2, 3` boxPos would be `-0.5, 1, -1.5`)

**TEST 2:**

*Code:*

```cs
private void OnDrawGizmos()
{
    //no need to care about extents... that's just box size
    //first child of the object is just an empty object... shifted by center values... this is always in the intended relative point of the object
    boxPos = transform.TransformPoint(gameObject.transform.GetChild(0).position);
    Gizmos.matrix = Matrix4x4.TRS(Vector3.zero, transform.rotation, transform.localScale);
    Gizmos.color = Color.red;
    Gizmos.DrawWireCube(boxPos, new Vector3(extents.x * 2, extents.y * 2, extents.z * 2));
}
```

*Result:*

> **0-0-0 POSITION:** it rendered perfectly as expected.

> **ROTATION:** makes it shift away (but around) from the object.

> **MOVEMENT:** also makes it shift way in the direction of movement (with a shift of value: `position * (center/2)` which makes the overall movement *1.5 of the expected movement every 1 unit in any direction)

**TEST 3:**

*Code:*

```cs
private void OnDrawGizmos()
{
    //no need to care about extents... that's just box size
    //first child of the object is just an empty object... shifted by center values... this is always in the intended relative point of the object
    boxPos = transform.TransformPoint(transform.InverseTransformPoint(gameObject.transform.GetChild(0).position));
    Gizmos.matrix = Matrix4x4.TRS(Vector3.zero, transform.rotation, transform.localScale);
    Gizmos.color = Color.red;
    Gizmos.DrawWireCube(boxPos, new Vector3(extents.x * 2, extents.y * 2, extents.z * 2));
}
```

*Result:*

> **0-0-0 POSITION:** it rendered perfectly as expected.

> **ROTATION:** makes it shift away (but around) the object.

> **MOVEMENT:** it works perfectly as expected.

**TEST 4:**

*Code:*

```cs
private void OnDrawGizmos()
{
    //center is a value I defined... it is the relative point
    //no need to care about extents... that's just box size
    Vector3 objectPosition = transform.position;
    Quaternion rotation = transform.rotation;
    point = transform.TransformPoint(transform.InverseTransformPoint(gameObject.transform.GetChild(0).position));
    boxPos = (rotation * (point - objectPosition)) + objectPosition;
    Gizmos.matrix = Matrix4x4.TRS(Vector3.zero, transform.rotation, transform.localScale);
    Gizmos.color = Color.red;
    Gizmos.DrawWireCube(boxPos, new Vector3(extents.x * 2, extents.y * 2, extents.z * 2));
}
```

*Result:*

> **0-0-0 POSITION:** it rendered perfectly as expected.

> **ROTATION:** makes it shift away (but around) the object.

> **MOVEMENT:** it works perfectly as expected.

**TEST 5:**

*Code:*

```cs
private void OnDrawGizmos()
{
    //center is a value I defined... it is the relative point
    //no need to care about extents... that's just box size
    //first child of the object is just an empty object... shifted by center values... this is always in the intended relative point of the object
    boxPos = Matrix4x4.TRS(Vector3.zero, transform.rotation, transform.localScale).inverse.MultiplyPoint(transform.GetChild(0).position);
    Gizmos.matrix = Matrix4x4.TRS(Vector3.zero, transform.rotation, transform.localScale);
    Gizmos.color = Color.red;
    Gizmos.DrawWireCube(boxPos, new Vector3(extents.x * 2, extents.y * 2, extents.z * 2));
}
```

*Result:*

> **0-0-0 POSITION:** it rendered perfectly as expected.

> **ROTATION:** it works perfectly as expected.

> **MOVEMENT:** it works perfectly as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your specific use case of having to cancel out the rotation and scale but not the position of a child, I would do this:

```
Vector3 boxPos = Matrix4x4.TRS(Vector3.zero, transform.rotation, transform.localScale)
        .inverse.MultiplyPoint(transform.GetChild(0).position);
```

---

Normally, I'd say you're already using a transform so just use [`InverseTransformPoint`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.InverseTransformPoint.html) to calculate the local position of the object and if you want to convert back to a world position you can use `TransformPoint`:

```
Transform target;
Vector3 relativePos;

// ...

Vector3 relativePos = transform.InverseTransformPoint(target.position);

// ...

Vector3 worldPos = transform.TransformPoint(relativePos);
```

Comment: I'm trying to use a relative Vector3... not a Transform

Comment: I have updated the problem... you can go check it out!

Comment: rotation breaks it

Comment: I use Gizmos to visualize only... I'm using it in collision calculations

Comment: also the child never moves(relative to its parent) which means its `relativePos` is always the same... so no need to be worried about calculating `relativePos`

Answer (score 0):

There is a math equation to solve this. Assuming you have `Quaternion rotation;` for the objects rotation, `Vector3 objectPosition;` for the game object and `Vector3 point;` for the point in local space, the equation is `(rotation * (point-objectPosition)) + objectPosition`

```
Vector3 objectPosition = transform.position;
Quaternion rotation = transform.rotation;
Vector3 point = Vector3(1, 0, 0);
Vector3 worldSpacePoint = (rotation * (point-objectPosition)) + objectPosition;
// if rotation is -90 degrees on the Y axis and objectPosition is zero, worldSpacePoint will be Vector3(0, 0, 1)
```

Comment: it's still not working

Comment: @RakoGames I ran some tests and it seems to be working fine on my end. Could you edit the post to show the code you have, and what the problem with it is?

Comment: I have updated the problem... you can go check it out!